# Does Raspberry Pi Pico C/C++ SDK Setup Script work on Raspberry Pi Desktop installed on a PC?

Tags: c++, pi-pico, raspberry-pi-desktop

The Raspberry Pi Pico documentation indicates "if you are intending to develop for Pico on a Raspberry Pi, then you can set up the C/C++ toolchain quickly by running our setup script from the command line".

Does anyone know if the setup script also works on the Raspberry Pi desktop installed on a PC?

Comment: what happens if you run the script?

Comment: @jsotola I didn't try. If it doesn't work, I don't want to mess up my desktop configuration with it only partially installed.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi Desktop is a Linux OS for PC with a Pi "look & feel".
Install a Linux tool for your hardware (probably X32).

Comment: I think it's more than just a "look & feel". They're both based on Debian Linux, but Raspberry Pi OS has moved on to Bullseye while Raspberry Pi desktop is still on Buster.

Comment: @StevenClark they are radically different! One uses ARM6 the other x32.